# Cut field one after one in shell script

Tags: shell-script

I have a data like this:

```
var1=col1,col2,col3,col4
```

I want to cut fields like that `col1` and `col3` should come together 
and `col2` and `col4` should come together.

So that my output variable should contain value like this.

```
var2=col1,col3
var3=col2,col4
```

Looking some help on this.

Comment: How many fields can you have? Will there always be 4? How many lines will you have? Only one or many? What scripting language will you be using? Should we assume bash-like syntax? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: echo "var1=col1,col2,col3,col4" | awk -F= '{print $2}' | awk -F, '{print $1","$3","$2","$4}'

Comment: Fields are dynamic. It can increase or decrease...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With POSIX shells:

```
var1=col1,col2,col3,col4
IFS=,
set -f
set -- $var1
unset var2 var3
while [ "$#" -ge 2 ]; do
  var2=$var2${var2+,}$1
  var3=$var3${var3+,}$2
  shift 2
done
```

With `zsh`:

```
unset var2 var3
for a b ("${(@s:,:)var1}") var2+=${var2+,}$a var3+=${var3+,}$b
```

Comment: It should work with Bourne shell too, shouldn't it?

Comment: @cuonglm, only if there are no empty cols. Some old versions of the Bourne shell didn't support `--` or would print all the variables upon `set --`. `set x $var1; shift` would be needed there.  Note that with POSIX compliant shells, my solution has a problem if the last col is empty.

Comment: its working but leaving one additional comma at beaning. Is there any approach to trim those additional comma form this function itself.

Comment: @SandeepSingh, possibly you're using [an earlier revision of the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/revisions/265748/1) where I had `var2= var3=` instead of `unset var2 var3`. `${var2+,}` expands to `,` iif var2 is set, to avoid the leading `,`.

Comment: Yes, I was using earlier version of answer and then I was trimming it to remove leading `,`.. Thanks for the clarification.